# "Referenced before assignment" error in conditional statement

Tags: python-2.7, arguments, keyword-argument

My code:

```
def sandwich(str, meat = 'ham', cheese = 'American'):

    if sandwich(str, meat = None, cheese = None):
        sandwich = str +' bread sandwich with turkey '
    else:
        sandwich = str +' bread sandwich with ' + meat + ' and '+ cheese + ' cheese'
    return sandwich
```

I tried using a definition parameter. That did not work. It gave me an error:

```
The local variable(sandwich) is being referenced before the assignment.
```

Please Help!

Comment: Please paste the code of the problem here, not in some external link.

Comment: def sandwich(str, meat = 'ham', cheese = 'American'):
    global sandwich
    if sandwich(str, meat = None, cheese = None):
        sandwich = str +' bread sandwich with turkey '
    else:
        sandwich = str +' bread sandwich with ' + meat + ' and '+ cheese + ' cheese'
    return sandwich

Comment: It's also in the description. The link is for the question.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and paste the code there, properly formatted. It's extremely hard to make out in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the post

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function again, and you are naming your variable the same name as the function.

Correcting both of these, and you end up with:

```
def sandwich(bread, meat='ham', cheese='american'):
    if meat == None and cheese == None:
        return '{} sandwich with turkey'.format(bread)
    return '{} sandwich with {} and {} cheese'.format(bread,
                                               meat, cheese)
```

Answer (score 0):

`def sandwich(` starts a **function** definition. `sandwich` will be the name of the function.

`sandwich =` starts an assignment. `sandwich` will be the name of the **variable**. Because you do this in a function body, the variable will be **local** and Python assumes you want `sandwich` to refer to that variable rather than to the function *within the whole body* of the function.

`sandwich(str, meat = None, cheese = None)` calls the function held in the local variable `sandwich`. (Remember that Python will assume you mean the local variable when you write `sandwich` within the function body.) But nothing has been assigned to that variable, yet, thus you get the mentioned error message.

I guess what you wanted to do is check the passed function arguments. If so, [Burhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33054443/674064) shows how you may do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sandwich(bread, meat='ham', cheese='american'):
    if meat == None and cheese == None:
        return '{} bread sandwich with turkey'.format(bread)
    return '{} bread sandwich with {} and {} cheese'.format(bread, meat, cheese)
```

I don't see how this will work.  If the values 'ham' and 'america' are set, how will the first if condition ever pass?  This will never return "{} bread sandwich with turkey" because the values are set.